# How to call a function from action before dispatching to reducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am working on a React Redux app. I have an action in which I am calling a utility function before dispatching the action.

```
import GetDataFromAPIs from "../utils/menu-creator";
export const UPDATE_DATA = 'UPDATE_DATA';

export const updateData = () => {
    const newData = GetDataFromAPIs();

    return{
        type: UPDATE_DATA, 
        payload: newData
    };
};
```

And, here is what GetDataFromAPIs.js is loosely doing:

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const apiOneData = axios.get('/api/a');
const apiTwoData = axios.get('/api/b');


const GetDataFromAPIs = () => {
    axios.all([apiOneData, apiTwoData]).then(axios.spread((...responses) => {
        var firstDataSet = responses[0].data
        var secondDataSet = responses[1].data;
        var dataObject = [];

        dataObject.push(firstDataSet);
        dataObject.push(secondDataSet);

        return dataObject;

    })).catch(errors => {
        console.log("There was an error.");
    })
}

export default GetDataFromAPIs;
```

But when the application runs **newData** is set as **undefined**. I am trying to step through GetDataFromAPIs.js but it traces till axios.all and then breaks out of the function. I don't see any error in the console.

So what I am guessing is that action is dispatched before the two axios.all is resolved. I thought this would be synchronous (newData will get the data back and then the action will be dispatched). Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: So I tried updating my code using await/async. I was calling the function this way: store.dispatch(updateData) but now it says I need to use a middleware. I tried store.dispatch(applyMiddleware(updateData)) but it's not working either. Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: Yeah, you need to `applyMiddleware` to your store, not the action. See my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly tell the action to `wait` to get that data asynchronously. To do that, make the following changes:

---

Your `GetDataFromAPIs` function should look this this:

```
const GetDataFromAPIs = async () => {
    // everything in here stays the same
}
```

And your `updateData` function should look like this:

```
export const updateData = async (dispatch) => {
    const newData = await GetDataFromAPIs();

    return dispatch({
        type: UPDATE_DATA, 
        payload: newData
    });
};
```

### Be sure to `dispatch` your action.

**Note:**

If you haven't got `redux-thunk` setup then you'll need to install that `npm` module and update your `createStore` to look something like this:

```
// other imports
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleWare(thunk))
```

Comment: I tried this and now I am getting this error: Parsing error: Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function

Comment: So I was calling the action this way: store.dispatch(updateData) but now it says I need to use a middleware. I tried store.dispatch(applyMiddleware(updateData)) but it's not working either. Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: Ah right, you haven't got thunks setup. I'm updating my answer.

Comment: Yes. I just tried it and it worked. I was am using thunk. So, I needed to pass dispatch as a parameter in my action. Thanks so much :).

Comment: Ah yes of course! Sorry I missed that! I'll update my answer for future people struggling :)

Answer (score 0):

I think [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) is what you need.

```
export const updateData = async () => {
    const newData = await GetDataFromAPIs();

    return{
        type: UPDATE_DATA, 
        payload: newData
    };
};


const GetDataFromAPIs = async () => {
  try {
    const responses = await axios.all([apiOneData, apiTwoData]).then(axios.spread((...responses);
    var firstDataSet = responses[0].data
    var secondDataSet = responses[1].data;
    var dataObject = [];

    dataObject.push(firstDataSet);
    dataObject.push(secondDataSet);

    return dataObject;

  } catch(errors) {
      console.log("There was an error.");
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`GetDataFromApis` doesn't return.

You should do

```js
const GetDataFromApis = async () => {
    return axios.all(...
```

`GetDataFromApis` will also return a `Promise` so you should `await` it in `updateData` like so:

```js
export const updateData = async () => {
    const newData = await GetDataFromAPIs();

    return {
        type: UPDATE_DATA, 
        payload: newData
    };
};
```

Comment: I tried this and now I am getting this error: Parsing error: Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function

Comment: Oups you have to make `updateData` async too. See my edit.

Comment: Be careful, `updateData` will now return a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Promise) so will need to use it in an async context.

Comment: So I was calling the function this way: store.dispatch(updateData) but now it says I need to use a middleware. I tried store.dispatch(applyMiddleware(updateData)) but it's not working either. Am I doing this wrong?